# How to exit from the text file editing mode, when the user write EXIT?

Tags: bash

#### Problem:

I want to find a proper way to exit from the text file editing, when the user write EXIT in file editing.

#### Script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
touch $1
read LINE
cat > $1
 if [[ "$LINE == "EXIT" ]]; then
 exit

fi
```

Comment: What is a "text file editing mode"? What do you mean by that? You mean to exit the `cat` command on a particular input from the user?

Comment: Yes, when the user write EXIT to txt file

Comment: To be exact: the user does not write to the txt file, the user "writes" to standard input of your program. Then the `cat` command outputs what the user inputs to standard output. Then `bash` redirects standard output of the `cat` program to the file.

Comment: You aren't in any kind of text editing mode. `cat` is simply reading from its standard input; type Control-D to signal the end of its input. The `bash` script is simply waiting for `cat` to exit, not monitoring anything that `cat` is reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read standard input line by line, output the line and check for the desired exit string.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n" "$LINE"
    if [[ $LINE == "EXIT" ]]; then
         break;
     fi
done > "$1"
```

Comment: This is what i have done but not working still
touch $1
cat > $1
while IFS = read -r line;do
if [[ $line == "EXIT" ]]; then
break;
fi
done > "$1"

Comment: remove `touch` and remove the `cat` and everything except shebang and the code I've posted...

Comment: Your code worked fine thank you for that. I am facing an error which is, when i exit from the code by writing EXIT then i want to display to content of the file. i used cat it shows input file is output file error and nothing get saved into the file,which is passed as as argument

Comment: So below the `done > "$1"` add the next command, ie. `cat "$1"`. It would be way easier if you would just post your program or reproducible example on pastebin or similar sites.